localhost 3001 refusing to connect
I was working on a project and my localhost3001 is continuously refusing to connect any solutions for thatheres the image of the issue that i am encountering 
I tried running my app but the localhost3001 refused to connect

Can you show the output of your terminal and the code you are executing to start the server at port 3001?

you need to post the code here with any error you find in console
